# Adding arguments to Packer's Ansible provisioner

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook, packer

My Friday brain is really struggling to convert an Ansible command line into the format my Packer .json wants. The Ansible:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e @env/users/user01.yml --ask-vault --ask-become
```

My attempted Packer block:

```
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "ansible_env_vars": ["ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False"],
      "playbook_file": "{{ template_dir }}/../path/playbook.yml",
      "type": "ansible",
      "user": "{{ user `ssh_username` }}",
      "extra_arguments": ["--extra-vars", "@env", "../path/env/users/user01.yml", "desktop=false", "--vault-password-file", "../vaultpass"]
    }
  ],
```

I've tried various combinations of key=value (like the docs say) instead of separate `"thing",` blocks but then it looks like Ansible is trying to read everything as one big argument for `--extra-vars` (whereas at least `--vault-password-file` should be separate I think?).

Answer (score 1):

OK `"extra_arguments": ["--extra-vars", "@../path/env/users/user01.yml", "-e", "desktop=false", "--vault-password-file", "../vaultpass"]` did the trick.